# How to group by a date with a timestamp? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timestamp, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in history | groupBy:'date'">
  <div>{{key}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in value">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show my history in this format:

```
2015-10-10
item 1
item 2
item 3

2015-10-11
item 4
item 5

2015-10-12
item 6
item 7
```

This code works correctly, but the `date` property is a timestamp. Each item differs by hours and seconds. It's important that the items are grouped by day without the time.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30509960/5159481) made by the [author](https://github.com/a8m) of [`angular-filter`](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) I found a nice solution using `momentjs`:

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in history | map: toDay | groupBy:'date'">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.toDay = toDay;

function toDay( history ) {
    history.day = moment( history.date ).format( "L" );
    return history;
}
```

Assuming you have a valid `javascript` `Date` object without using `momentjs` your function would be alike:

```
function toDay( history ) {
    history.date = history.date.toLocaleDateString();
    return history;
};
```

Comment: how would i do this on the javascript side?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this for hours as a backend developer but I realised you can use time ago it's the same as moment but it can quit ckly format your timestamp.

E.g groupBy | datesubmitted : timeago then it will group by hours, days and etc